# Cannot fix the Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, grid, alignment

```
...
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 120.0, 
      left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: 
         MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: 
                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "SERVICE TYPE",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: 
                             FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(
                  "LOCATION",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: 
                             FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: 
            CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text(
                "SERVICE TYPE",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: 
                         FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text(
                "LOCATION",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: 
                         FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
         ],
        ),
       ),
...
```

Please help to fix this "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" error. What I need is a row and in side that 2 columns with many text widgets inside each column. Those text widgets should not overflow. That's why I used an expanded widget. But now I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both `Expanded` widget wrapping the `Column`

And add `crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to your top `Row widget`